# Function for replacing characters

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a new function for replacing one characters with others:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST (sifra in varchar2)  
RETURN  VARCHAR2 AS 
sifra1 varchar2(16);
BEGIN
       select    case  when instr(sifra,'A') >0 then replace(sifra, 'A', '0') 
                 when instr(sifra,'B') >0 then replace(sifra, 'B', '1') 
                 when instr(sifra,'C') >0 then replace(sifra, 'C', '2') 
                 when instr(sifra,'D') >0 then replace(sifra, 'D', '3')
                 when instr(sifra,'E') >0 then replace(sifra, 'E', '4') 
                 when instr(sifra,'F') >0 then replace(sifra, 'F', '5')
                 when instr(sifra,'G') >0 then replace(sifra, 'G', '6')
                 when instr(sifra,'H') >0 then replace(sifra, 'H', '7')
                 when instr(sifra,'I') >0 then replace(sifra, 'I', '8')
                 when instr(sifra,'J') >0 then replace(sifra, 'J', '9')
                 end 
                 into sifra1 from dual;
                 return sifra1;

END TEST;
```

But when I try to use that function in query I get all `null` values as a output.

```
select test(sifra) from iis.artikli
```

What's wrong is here?

Comment: You need to pass uppercase as you are checking the uppercase character only. Do `select test('SIFRA') from iis.artikli`. Also note the single quote for passing varchar.

Comment: @Ofisora I am not sure is it that correct, with modification in case when, I have results

Comment: That's good if it has been solved. I assumed that sifra is the word you are passing as a parameter.

Comment: @Ofisora Thanks for comment anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I didn't put else in case when.

```
create or replace FUNCTION test (sifra in varchar2)  
RETURN  VARCHAR2 AS 
sifra1 varchar2(16);
BEGIN
       select    case  when instr(sifra,'A') >0 then replace(sifra, 'A', '0') 
                 when instr(sifra,'B') >0 then replace(sifra, 'B', '1') 
                 when instr(sifra,'C') >0 then replace(sifra, 'C', '2') 
                 when instr(sifra,'D') >0 then replace(sifra, 'D', '3')
                 when instr(sifra,'E') >0 then replace(sifra, 'E', '4') 
                 when instr(sifra,'F') >0 then replace(sifra, 'F', '5')
                 when instr(sifra,'G') >0 then replace(sifra, 'G', '6')
                 when instr(sifra,'H') >0 then replace(sifra, 'H', '7')
                 when instr(sifra,'I') >0 then replace(sifra, 'I', '8')
                 when instr(sifra,'J') >0 then replace(sifra, 'J', '9')
                 else sifra
                 end 
                 into sifra1 from dual;
                 return sifra1;

END test;
```

Now work just fine